# Why Read() in the Console class is returning an integer?

Tags: c#

I have a simple code as follows

```
   int n=Console.Read();
   Console.WriteLine(n);
```

When I gave 100 as input it is printing only 49 which is ASCII decimal for 1 and then what about the remaining zeros. I also found in the msdn website as "The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read." and Read() has a integer return type. Actually is it returning the number of characters read ? Then what is the use of it?

Comment: The documentation you quoted is your answer. "Returns the next character from the input stream". Well, the first character you typed was 1.... clearly the remaining 0s are still in the stream.

Comment: "next character" ie a letter not an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the next character in the input stream. 
1 is the first thing you input, and the 0's must be still in the input stream.
The `int` value you were getting is a `char` being cast as an `int`. 
If you change `int n` to `char n` (and cast it as a char) the output will be "1".